# Better way to find Class in event.target parentnodes using jquery and javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently, I check the target of the input box keyup event to see if it is contained within a div wit class "editorRow" using:

var $parentClass = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className;

Is there a better way to do this in case extra markup is added between the div and the span tags?

```
  <div class="editorRow">
     <li>
       <span class="wi1">
          <input type="text" value="" style="width: 80px;" name="LineItems9"  id="LineItems_9">
       </span>
     </li>  
   </div>
```

```
$("input").live("keyup", function(event) {

    return GiveDynamicFieldsLife(event);

});

function GiveDynamicFieldsLife(event) {

    **var $parentClass = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className;**

    if ($parentClass == "editorRow") {
    //Do Stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("input").live("keyup", function() {

    GiveDynamicFieldsLife(this);

});

function GiveDynamicFieldsLife(elem) {

    var $parentClass = $(elem).closest('.editorRow');

      if ($parentClass) {
        //Do Stuff
      }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 function GiveDynamicFieldsLife(event) {
   var $parentClass = $(event.target).parents('.editorRow');

   if ($parentClass.length) {
   //Do Stuff
   }
}
```